# Relation between focus and camera intrinsic parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, computer-science, 3d, image-processing

Does a focus tuning affect the camera intrinsic parameters?
More precisely, if the focus of a camera is changed, does the camera intrinsic parameters matrix remain unchanged?

Apparently, since this matrix involves only the  focal length, image sensor format, and principal points of the lens (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning)), it should not be changed by a focus tuning; but this is clear for me if the camera contains a single lens only; in general, a camera contains several lens, say 2, and the focus changes the distance between these two lens. So, if this pair of lenses can be seen as a single lens, what does prevent the focus tuning to modify the "intrinsic characteristics" of this equivalent lens?